# Git: How to swap two files

Tags: git, swap

How can I swap two files, keeping them marked so in the history?
(Except for doing it manually.)

I'd expect some flag for `git mv`, like,

```
git mv --swap foo.txt bar.txt
```

which would produce

```
# renamed:    foo.txt -> bar.txt
# renamed:    bar.txt -> foo.txt
```

Is there support for this in git?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git doesn't actually track renames, it just determines that heuristically based on the changes in content of a particular commit.  If you do what you describe, you'll likely see something like below but it depends on the files.

```
Modified: foo.txt
Renamed: foo.txt -> bar.txt
```

Comment: Interesting. I tried the steps described in http://effectif.com/git/swapping-two-files-in-git, and what I got was not renamed, renamed but copied, renamed.

Answer (score 1):

git doesn't store info that some file was renamed to another file so the question makes no sense.